# How to efficiently ignore unassigned parent ip address networks?

Tags: python, networking, ip, python-requests, ip-address

I am crawling through the ARIN whois API to find all network ranges. The code below takes a starting IP address, sends it to ARIN, and returns the ending IP address of that network. That ending address is then incremented by one, and this new value becomes the next address sent to ARIN. This works well, but it is inefficient when ISPs have swaths of unassigned addresses because each starting address has to be checked until another assigned network is found.

The code is a self-contained example that shows how there are a few network ranges assigned, and then a period of addresses that are unassigned by AT&T. How should these unassigned networks be checked without checking each and every address?

```
import requests
from ipaddress import ip_address

IPAddress = str.replace('12.31.71.56','.','-')

while True:
    try:
        url = 'https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-' + IPAddress + '-1.json'
        request = requests.get(url)
        response = request.json()
        endAddress = response['net']['endAddress']['$']
        IPAddress = str.replace((ip_address(endAddress) + 1).compressed,'.','-')
        print(IPAddress)
        print(response['net']['orgRef']['@name'])
    except ValueError:
        IPAddress = str.replace(IPAddress,'-','.')
        IPAddress = str.replace((ip_address(IPAddress) + 1).compressed,'.','-')
        print(IPAddress)
    if IPAddress == '12-31-71-150':
        break
```

Comment: Looks like there's nothing better than trying every address sequentially. The `WHOIS` service allows wildcard patterns, but I don't see anything similar in the REST API.

Comment: do you think that's a realistic thing to do if all undefined ranges (i.e. 127, 192.168) are not checked? I'm struggling to quantify whether it's even possible. I know it would be a lot less than the 4B public IPv4 addresses due to skipping to the end of assigned ranges and ignoring undefined ranges, but it still may be too much.

Comment: Check the API documentation to see if there's a way to find all the blocks within another block. Then you can work from the top down rather than scanning. But I don't think they've designed this to make it easy to list everything, just to look up specific information.

Comment: yeah - i've scoured the documentation for something like that to no avail, unfortunately. thanks for the thoughts!